# Loop multidimensional array from mysql database using php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I can't for the life me return single values of my multidimensional array from database. For example, I want to return the value of each key to return in table columns.

This is the array coming from the database:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => lvzr0001
            [fname] => Hamza
            [lname] => ibrahimi
            [student_email] => Hamza_ib2@hotmail.com
            [course] => CPAN 220 D30
            [full_name] => asdfddd
            [institution] => asdf
            [position] => sadf
            [proc_email] => Hamza_ib2@hotmail.com
            [phone] => 14168334599
            [address] => 20 edgecliffe golfway
            [city] => Toronto
            [prov_state] => Ont
            [postal_code] => M3C 3A4
            [country] => Canada
            [comments] =>  adfadsfasdfasdfas
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 56gfdsgdfs
            [fname] => zxcv
            [lname] => cvcvz
            [student_email] => dsfb2@hotmail.com
            [course] => ELIC 101 90
            [full_name] => dfa
            [institution] => asdf
            [position] => zxcvzxcv
            [proc_email] => zxcvzxvc@hotmail.com
            [phone] => 4002452345
            [address] => 102 yorkland st
            [city] => Richmond Hill
            [prov_state] => Ont
            [postal_code] => l4s1a1
            [country] => Canada
            [comments] => xzcvzxcv
        )

)
```

I want to get a specific column result like this:

```php
<?php
global $wpdb;
$displayQuery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM viewoffcampusproctorrequests");

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($displayQuery);
echo '</pre>';

foreach($displayQuery as $key => $value){
  foreach($value as $title => $description){
    echo $description['fname'];
  }
}
```

But I only get the entire key values when I `echo $description;`. How would I access each key item in my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close: `$value` is an object, so you can retrieve a particular key/value pair. If you want the value for `fname` for each object:

```
foreach($displayQuery as $key => $value){
   echo $value->fname;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I can't rate your answer for some reason.